# Whats the difference between these two functions

Tags: php, python

I created a function in PHP first and then following it tried to make the same thing in Python. Following are my codes

Python:

```
def bfs(my_data):
      my_queue = []
      my_queue.insert(0, my_data[0]); 
      my_data[0]['visited'] = '1';
      while my_queue:
                vertex = my_queue.pop()
                print(vertex['letter'])

      for n_vertex in vertex['neighbors']:
                int_vertex = int(n_vertex)-1
                if my_data[int_vertex]['visited'] is '0':
                          my_data[int_vertex]['visited'] = '1'
                          test.insert(0, my_data[int_vertex])
                          my_queue = str(test)
```

PHP:

```
function bfs($my_data)
{
    $my_queue = array(); //array to store vertices
    array_unshift($my_queue, $my_data[0]); // pass the first value to the first index of queue
    $my_data[0]['visited'] = true; // value for visited is set to true for the first vertix
    //print_r($my_queue);
    while(!empty($my_queue))
    {
        $vertex = array_pop($my_queue); // passing the last value of queue to vertex
        echo $vertex['letter'];

        $msg = $vertex['letter'];
        $output_file = $_POST["output_file_name"];
        $output_file_path = "../SPA/" . $output_file;
        $outfile = fopen($output_file_path, 'aw'); //writing output to the file
        fwrite($outfile, $msg);
        fclose($outfile);         
        // fwrite($outfile, $msg);


        foreach($vertex['neighbours'] as $n_vertex)
        {
            //print_r($n_vertex);
            if(!$my_data[$n_vertex-1]['visited'])
            {
                $my_data[$n_vertex-1]['visited'] = true; // set visited true after visiting each neighbour
                array_unshift($my_queue, $my_data[$n_vertex-1]); //pass the neighbours to queue
            }
        } 




    }

}
```

I believe both are same functions but as i am getting different results i am trying to find out the difference. What do you think? Also, if they are different can you tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a broad question (what results are you seeing, what do you suspect?) But, for one thing, the `for` loop in Python is not indented to be within the `while`, whereas in PHP it is inside the `while` loop.